# Is there a specified order for data replication among different partitions in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-replication

I have 1 write region (e.g., `US`), and 2 read regions (e.g., `US` and `EU`). I have a collection, and I want to write into it, using different partition keys. I wonder, is there a specified order for data replication among different partitions in Cosmos DB? If I am not mistaken, according to [Consistency levels in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels), the order is specified only within the same partition key. Is it correct?

For example, is it possible to have the following case:

1. I write an `object 1` with `partition key 1` in `US` region
2. I write an `object 2` with `partition key 2` in `US` region
3. I read an `object 2` in `EU` region => `found`
4. I read an `object 1` in `EU` region => `not found`

Comment: Probably better to ask on [sf], as this is not a programming question - more of a specific service operational question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon sorry, perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but why isn't this considered a programming question? As a software engineer, I need to understand how Cosmos DB replicates data in order to write my code correctly.